# ubuntu 18.04 - I destroyed my network manually how can I set it to autoconfigure

Tags: networking, 18.04

My machine no longer connects to my adsl  modem on address 192.168.1.1
Looking at my network I see my machine IP address is 127.0.1.1. I need my machine to autoconfigure, my modem is switched on and working ok. Network-manager missing from machine,I only have network settings

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do, is to seriously check which interfaces I have on my computer.

You could run one of these commands and check the output:

```
sudo ifconfig
```

or

```
sudo ip addr show
```

With that, you are already able to set the dhcp mode for your interface.

Assuming the name of your interface is: ens2

Run the command:

```
sudo ifconfig up ens2
```

This command is necessary as your default network interface is probably not up. Starting from the line that the only ip you mentioned is 127.0.1.1, which is usually called the lo interface. Remember to change ens2 to the name of your network interface!

Then, set the interface to work in dhcp mode:

```
sudo dhclient ens2
```

After that, remove the cable and connect it again. Starting from the beginning that the connection is via cable ... Or disable the wifi and enable it again if it is a wifi connection. Try to retake the test.

[edit]

You mentioned that you no longer have the network-manager ...
Sorry, I missed this part of the question ...

"Network-manager missing from machine ..."

What is the exit if the manager is restarted?

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions which got me some way there.

In the end had to edit the interfaces file and start networking:
vi interfaces
sudo vi interfaces
cat interfaces
sudo systemctl start  networking